# Is it possible to overlay HTML over XBAP?

Tags: html, iframe, overlay, xbap

Is it possible to overlay HTML elements over XBAP?

I have an XBAP application in an iframe on a webpage, and I'm trying to overlay HTML elements over it. I can easily do it over Flash, but I have yet to figure out how to do it over XBAP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with XBAP.  If you can use Silverlight then a solution is available to using Windowless controls ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156(VS.95).aspx)).